# Printing unicode text with python

Tags: python, text, unicode, export, xlrd

I have a dictionary that is filled with lists where the data was read from an excel file. All of the text is unicode however I do not have any special characters. I am trying to write the data that is located in the lists to a .txt file but I'm having trouble printing the lists out.

```
target.write("move % to 100 100") % product[1][0]
target.write("\n move % to 200 100") % product[1][1]
target.write("\n connect % to %") % (product[1][0], product[1][1])
```

product is the dictionary that holds the multiple lists. is there an easy way to format my .write statement so it can accept unicode. the error I'm getting is

```
"Type Error: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Nonetype' and 'unicode'
```

Comment: added a solution but just deleted it because the typecast only worked on my print statement but not for me .write statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot just found out that I can type cast product so str(product[1][0]) accomplishes my needs

Comment: i typecasted the product into a variable like string1 and then used string1 in my .write statement

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the parameters to the format strings not being inside the `write` parentheses.  `target.write(...)` returns `None` so you are effectively processing:

```
None % product[1][0]
```

Another problem '%' is not a string formatting command by itself.  `%s` is probably what you want.  If you are using Python 2.X your format strings are *not* Unicode.  Add `u` in front of the strings.

Here's the fixes:

```
target.write(u"move %s to 100 100" % product[1][0])
target.write(u"\n move %s to 200 100" % product[1][1])
target.write(u"\n connect %s to %s" % (product[1][0], product[1][1]))
```

Or use the new `.format` method:

```
target.write(u"move {} to 100 100".format(product[1][0]))
target.write(u"\n move {} to 200 100".format(product[1][1]))
target.write(u"\n connect {} to {}".format(product[1][0], product[1][1]))
```